How to reveal Minesweeper tiles with no mines recursively?
I'm trying to make Minesweeper using JavaScript and I wanted to make a bit of code so that when you reveal a tile with no adjacent mines it reveals the tiles next to it. If any of those tiles also have no adjacent mines, they reveal their neighbouring tiles too. This should continue until you have revealed a field of tiles without adjacent mines and all of the tiles next to them.
mines is a 2D array. If the value is 1 there is a mine.
minesNearby is a 2D array where each value is the number of mines next to the tile at that position.
checkedTiles is a 2D array. If the value is 1 the tile has been clicked.
findNeighbours returns an array of all the positions of the tiles around a given tile. (e.g. [[19,5],[19,4],[19,3],[18,3]...)
updateTile updates the tile div in the HTML.


function updateTile(y,x) {
  let tile = d.gid(`tile${y}-${x}`)
  tile.classList.add(mines[y][x]==1?'mine':num2str(minesNearby[y][x]));
  tile.innerHTML = minesNearby[y][x];
}

function openTile(y,x) {  

  console.log(`opening tile y ${y} and x ${x}`)  
  checkedTiles[y][x] = 1;  
  updateTile(y,x);  
  if (mines[y][x] == 1) {  
    // death  
  } else if (minesNearby[y][x] == 0) {  
    findNeighbours(y,x).forEach((tile,index) => {  
      console.log(`${tile[0]}+${tile[1]}`)  
      if (checkedTiles[tile[0]][tile[1]] == 0) {  
        openTile(tile[0],tile[1])  
      };  
    });  
  }  
}

function findNeighbours(y,x) {
  let o = [];
  let yy = { u: y+1>=board.h, l: y<=0 } //checks if the number is outofrange or almost outofrange
  let xx = { u: x+1>=board.w, l: x<=0 }
  if ( !yy.u          ) { o.push([ y+1,   x ]) }
  if ( !yy.u && !xx.u ) { o.push([ y+1, x+1 ]) }
  if ( !xx.u          ) { o.push([   y, x+1 ]) }
  if ( !yy.l && !xx.u ) { o.push([ y-1, x+1 ]) }
  if ( !yy.l          ) { o.push([ y-1,   x ]) }
  if ( !yy.l && !xx.l ) { o.push([ y-1, x-1 ]) }
  if ( !xx.l          ) { o.push([   y, x-1 ]) }
  if ( !yy.u && !xx.l ) { o.push([ y+1, x-1 ]) }
  return o
}
.row {display:flex;}

.tile {
  display    : inline-block;
  width      : 30px;
  height     : 30px;
  background : #999;
  border     : 3px outset #bbb;
  box-sizing : border-box;
}

.tile.mine {
  background-color: #000;
}

.tile.one   { color: #11e; }
.tile.two   { color: #1e1; }
.tile.three { color: #e11; }
.tile.four  { color: #91e; }
.tile.five  { color: #e91; }
.tile.six   { color: #1ee; }
.tile.seven { color: #555; }
.tile.eight { color: #333; }
.tile.nine  { color: #000; }
<div id="board"></div>



This looks fine to me, but I'm sure there's something I'm missing.
When you click a tile with no adjacent mines, it sometimes will reveal the tile to the top-left and sometimes will not reveal anything. (The top-left tile isn't even the first in the findNeighbours array).
If there are more tiles with no adjacent mines to the top left, a diagonal line of revealed tiles may occur.
How do I make this work properly?

Post code as a [mcve] and include HTML as well as findNeighbours().

Your question is difficult to answer without a minimal reproducible example, as requested by zer00ne in the comments.
Although not recursive, Mister Jojo recommends this solution specifically avoiding recursion.
Your function looks alright, but I would recommend that you move the check for checkedTiles[][] to the start of your function instead of during your loop through the neighbors. Something like this:
function openTile(y, x) {

 // Check here!
 if(checkedTiles[y][x]) return;

 console.log(`opening tile y ${y} and x ${x}`);
 checkedTiles[y][x] = 1;
 updateTile(y, x);
 if(mines[y][x] == 1) {
  // death
 } else if(minesNearby[y][x] == 0) {
  findNeighbors(y, x).forEach(([y, x], index)) {
   console.log(`${y}+${x}`);
   openTile(y, x);
  }
 }
}

This will prevent any code from running if the tile was opened previously, which may be the problem -- depending on your updateTile() function which we can't see.
I recommend this because I ended up making a working function similar to yours. Pared down, it looks very similar:
function openTile(mine) {
 if(mine.opened) return;
 mine.opened = true;
 if(mine.mine) {
  // death
 } else {
  if(mine.nearby == 0) {
   mine.neighbors.forEach(neighbor => neighbor.open());
  }
 }
}

Without more information about your code, this is the extent of how much I can assist you, but I have included my working example here if it helps. It uses arrays of objects rather than arrays of numbers, but the function names and parameters should look similar. Hopefully this is helpful to you.


var mines, size = 10, explosive = 0.25;
function start() {
 mines = [];
 for(var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  mines[i] = [];
  for(var n = 0; n < size; n++) {
   mines[i][n] = {
    x: n,
    y: i,
    mine: Math.random() <= explosive,
    opened: false,
    get nearby() { return minesNearby(this.x, this.y); },
    get neighbors() { return findNeighbors(this.x, this.y); },
    open: function(initial) { openTile(this.x, this.y, initial); }
   }
  }
 }
}

function restart() {
 var game = document.querySelector('#game')
 game.innerHTML = '';
 game.classList.remove('won');
 start();
 createTiles();
}

function createTiles() {
 for(var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  for(var n = 0; n < size; n++) {
   var tile = document.createElement('button');
   tile.mine = mines[i][n];
   tile.mine.tile = tile;
   tile.addEventListener('click', function() { this.mine.open(); }, { once: true });
   document.querySelector('#game').append(tile);
  }
 }
}

function minesNearby(x, y) {
 return findNeighbors(x, y).filter(v => v.mine).length;
}

function findNeighbors(x, y) {
 var neighbors = [];
 for(var i = Math.max(0, y-1); i < y+2 && i < mines.length; i++) {
  for(var n = Math.max(0, x-1); n < x+2 && n < mines[i].length; n++) {
   neighbors.push(mines[i][n]);
  }
 }
 return neighbors;
}

function openTile(x, y, initial = true) {
 var mine = mines[y][x];
 if(mine.opened) return;
 mine.opened = true;
 mine.tile.classList.add('open');
 if(mine.mine) {
  mine.tile.innerHTML = '&#8251;';
  mine.tile.classList.add('mine');
  openAll();
  if(initial) setTimeout(() => alert('You exploded!'), 10);
 } else {
  if(mine.nearby == 0) {
   mine.neighbors.forEach(neighbor => neighbor.open());
  }
  mine.tile.innerText = mine.nearby;
  mine.tile.style.color = `hsl(${120-120*(mine.nearby/8)}, 100%, 20%)`;
 }
 if(initial && didWin()) {
  document.querySelector('#game').classList.add('won');
  openAll();
  setTimeout(() => alert('You win!'), 10);
 }
}

function openAll() {
 mines.forEach(row => row.forEach(mine => mine.open(false)));
}

function didWin() {
 return mines.every(row => row.every(mine => (mine.opened && !mine.mine) || (!mine.opened && mine.mine)));
}

start();

addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
 document.querySelector('#restart').addEventListener('click', restart);
 createTiles();
})
#game {
 --size: 2rem;
 display: flex;
 margin: 2px;
 width: calc(var(--size) * 10 + 18px);
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 gap: 2px;
 button {
  flex-basis: var(--size);
  appearance: none;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  max-height: var(--size);
  padding: 0;
  border: calc(var(--size) / 6) outset #EEE;
  background: #EEE;
  font-size: calc(var(--size) / 2);
  color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
 }
 button#restart {
  width: auto;
 }
 button:hover:not(:active, .open) {
  background: #F0F0F0;
  border-color: #E0E0E0;
 }
 button:is(:active, .open) {
  border-style: inset;
 }
 .mine {
  background: #700;
  color: white;
 }
 &.won .mine {
  background: #070;
 }
}
<div id='game'></div>
<button id='restart'>Restart</button>




The problem with a recursive algorithm is the risk of stack overflow in the case of a large grid.

That's true. I did write it differently than I might have due to the layout of the code presented in the question. Honestly, I saw this question and thought minesweeper might be a fun little challenge.

I'm not too invested in this question, but it seems as though this question was specifically about recursion. Whether or not it is the best solution, it may be for a school assignment about recursion -- or simply the simplicity of the code. Your solution for the other question works quite well and it's well worded, but I wouldn't necessarily say that this is a duplicate question.

Ok, let's see where this takes us, although I fundamentally think using a recursive algorithm is a mistake.
